# Automatically send email notification to assigned people and specific people when field changes?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am using the issue tracking template to track tasks. When new items are created or changed, an email notification with a summary of the entire item is sent to all people are assigned to the form.

In addition, I want to set up a workflow where:
1. Field A changes to "Request for Update"
2. Email is automatically sent to people X, Y, Z

I can get both types of notifications to work independently, but as soon as I try to add this conditional workflow, I lose my auto emails to assigned persons upon changes.

How can I keep the template workflow (auto email to all assigned persons) and implement this conditional email at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use two separate workflows you could combine them into one.  If the only piece you are wanting to use from the first workflow is a notification email to the `Assigned To`, you can add that into your second workflow pretty easily.

Make sure the workflow runs on change (so it will run every time) and at the beginning of your workflow add in the `Send Email` action. Construct the email however you would like and place the `Assigned To` field in as the `To:`.

If you have the second part already working in your own workflow you shouldn't have to touch that part of it.  Just add the above to the existing workflow.